# Skype call via RDP on terminal server - Windows Server 2003

Tags: rdp, terminal-server, windows-server-2003-r2, audio, skype

I tried calling with Skype on terminal server on Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2. I enable sound over RDP with a Windows Server 2003 virtual machine. ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110829185835/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/eknowlogy/archive/2006/06/30/83673.aspx))

I used the latest Skype but I have problem with audio transfer via RDP.

[image: rdp and skype audio settings]

I use an HP Thin Client which has Windows XP Embedded SP2 installed.

In thin client I connect headphone set.

I use MSTC (RDP) for connection to terminal server.

When I try make a call from skype I get this error message.

**Problem with playback devices.**

[image: skype error]

I found some external solutions as:

http://www.sound-over-rdp.com/

I google it, but I am not sure if it is possible make a skype call via RDP on terminal server.

Also on terminal server can run now only one instance of skype. For example one user1 is log on na terminal server and use skype, then user2 connect to terminal server but he can not log on to skype.

Is it possible to run Skype on a terminal server, and if so please describe how.

**Or it exist another technology like MSTSC / RDP support SKYPE CALLING.**

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to transmit audio from a client computer to a Windows 2003 Terminal server.  It is not supported.  I suppose there is a remote possibility that you could get Skype to accept a call and receive audio, but there is no possibility for you to transmit.

Windows 2008 R2 introduced a feature, to permit audio redirection, but it is not enabled on the terminal server by default.  AFAIK, not linux-based thin client or remote desktop application supports sending audio.  You need the [7.0 version](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084) of the remote desktop connector on Windows to support recording redirection.  This isn't going to be available on an embedded version of XP service pack 2.

See this Microsoft document for setting it up audio recording redirection.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759231.aspx

> terminal server can run now only one instance of skype

I highly doubt you will be able to get multiple copies of Skype running.  I would be somewhat surprised if you could get a single connection running.  AFAIK Skype is not officially support on a terminal server at all.